# java.sql.sqlException: Unexpected token: FIRST_VALUE

Tags: oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working on a legacy system using java 6 and oracle db and spring 3.0 jdbcTemplate.

The query which I am trying to execute is:

```
SELECT department_id, last_name, salary, FIRST_VALUE(last_name)
  OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS lowest_sal
  FROM (SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department_id = 90
    ORDER BY employee_id)
  ORDER BY department_id, last_name, salary, lowest_sal;
```

But I am getting the following error:

java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: FIRST_VALUE in statement 
    [SELECT department_id, last_name, salary, FIRST_VALUE(last_name)
          OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS ...]

Running the same query in sql developer runs fine. I am clueless what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like an issue with the client version that your Java 6 app implements, instructions like FIRST_VALUE and the window construction (the OVER clause) may not be supported in older clients as they where incorporated to the DBMS since 9i version.

I've run into problems such as, a "not valid" CASE condition within a select statement when I try to use it in Forms6i environment, since the built-in client for that version can't parse the statement, even though I'm connecting to a 11g DBMS.

A solution to this may be create a stored procedure in your DB to retrieve your data and then execute and read the results from your app.